# Duplicating an entire artwork with contents within it only returns white background - why?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

I want to duplicate an entire artboard with all the artworks within it to another location in Illustrator CC, and I think it can be done by pressing `⌥` and dropping and dragging. However, when I tried it, the resultant artwork is only made up by the entire white background, and all the artworks within the original artboard were not duplicated properly.

And I tried to push the white background back in order to confirm that it just hides all the artworks behind it, but the artworks wasn't hidden.

So how can I duplicate the entire artwork with all the contents within it?

Comment: Is anything locked? Items? layers?

Comment: I remove one locked layer but the duplication still doesn't work.

Comment: Clipping masks anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you are just trying to duplicate the artboard within the same file, you should be able to just pick `Duplicate Artboards` from the **Artboards** panel.

[image: Artboards]
As @Lauren Ipsum noted though, you need to be sure all of the content you wish to have duplicated is unlocked. I recommend going to `Object > Unlock All` or pressing <kbd>⌘ / Ctrl / Command</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ / Alt / option</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> before duplicating the artboard.

Answer (score 0):

This could mean a whole lot different things have gone wrong while copying. I don't think you can copy an artboard from an active document to another, but they are fast workarounds to this.
Is it a vector art or flattened/rasterized? Are the layers locked? 
I am not sure about the key combination you are referring to but on Windows, copying is done by ALT + drag the item

Answer (score 0):

[image: Adobe Illustrator CS6]


This is issue was driving me bonkers and I found the solution. I think the OP wanted to use the shortcut to copy the entire clipboard.

Switch to Artboard mode. Shift + Option (Mac) Shift + Alt (PC)

Look for this button on the top button bar. Toggles the ability to copy the artboard contents. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the background layer lock before duplicating.